# grep - a simple issue with end of line

Tags: linux, unix, grep

```
ls -alp $base/$currentDir |  awk '{print $9}'  | grep '/' | egrep -v '^t|^tz$|^html$|^\.'
```

I have this grep and I am trying to ignore matches with "t" "tz" or "html" full names of directories.
All is good except that ^html$ does not match, while ^html does match, same for ^tz$ not matching -- somehow the $ is not being recognized as end of line. ^ is fine as start of line.

I really want to know the answer to the above, and secondarily, is there a different way to get list of all subdirectories in a given directory?

I found ls -d but that does not take directory parameter?:

```
ls -d * /
/  arch  index.html
```

that works fine
but unsucessful tries:

```
abc> ls -d * /
/  arch  index.html
abc> ls -d ../../arizona /
../../arizona  /
abc> ls -d ../../arizona  
../../arizona
abc ls -d '../../arizona'
../../arizona
abc> ls -d '../../arizona' /
../../arizona  /
```

while this is the layout

```
abc> ls -alp ../../arizona | grep '/'
drwxr-xr-x   7 roberto007 inetuser  4096 Jan 26 11:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 205 roberto007 inetuser 28672 Mar 10 11:07 ../
drwxr-xr-x   3 roberto007 inetuser  4096 Jan 26 11:17 grand-canyon/
drwxr-xr-x   3 roberto007 inetuser  4096 Jan 26 11:16 havasu-falls/
drwxr-xr-x   2 roberto007 inetuser 28672 Feb 27  2014 html/
drwxr-xr-x   4 roberto007 inetuser  4096 Jan 26 11:17 sedona/
drwxr-xr-x   3 roberto007 inetuser  4096 Jan 26 11:16 superstitions/
```

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -alp` in the question.  See [Why parsing 'ls' output is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as well.

Comment: The `-p` option puts a `/` at the end of the directory name and that's why your matches are failing.

Comment: that's it codeforester, thank you, missing /, should be ^t/$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
cd $base/$currentDir
printf '%s\n' */ | egrep -v '^t|^tz/$|^html/$'
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' $base/$currentDir/*/ | egrep -v '^t|^tz/$|^html/$'
```

- `*/` lists only directories
- `printf '%s\n'` puts a newline after each directory
- `egrep` does what you want, no need to filter out `./` because hidden directories are not expanded by `*/`